# Community shouldn't bump before flags are cleared

Tags: support, flags, closed-questions, moderator-tools, community-user

I found flags in the moderator dashboard queue (from different users) about two separate questions asked by the same user.

I commented on and closed both questions.

In most cases, this would mean that the issue had been dealt with.

However, in this case, the Community user decided to add a "Consecutive closed questions" flag to the second question.

1. What is the purpose of the consecutive closed questions flag?
2. Why didn't the previous flag get cleared when I closed the question?
3. Should I mark the flag as valid or invalid?
4. Does marking the flags as valid or invalid automatically apply to both flags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The consecutive closed questions is generally to note that "Hey, this user has had a lot of questions closed in a row, you should investigate". It's kinda like the "20 comments posted" or "Lotsa editing" flags that are shown for things we might not yet be alerted to. It's generally more useful for repeated closures done by the community, so I imagine Stack Overflow probably gets a whole lot more mileage out of it.
2. Are you sure the original flag wasn't actually cleared? If it's in grey, it has been already cleared; it's just left visible to help in judgment with any new flags that turn up. If it wasn't cleared, my take would be that it is a bug.
3. Generally, Community doesn't matter on this regard. Community's flag weight is somewhat ignored when it comes to position in the queue. But in general - valid if you think the multiple closures was something worth investigating that user for, invalid if you think Community user is a sack of potatoes.
4. It applies to all live flags (i.e. the ones whose reasons are not shown in grey).

Comment: 2. No, I'm not sure.  I cleared it already.  However, I don't think it was grey.

Comment: 3. Why bother?  Does anyone care (or know, or analyze) if I think the community user is a sack of potatoes?

Comment: 4. That makes some sense, but I wasn't aware of it.  Will have to keep this in mind when dealing with non-community users.

Comment: The 20 comments posted flag is pretty damned useless.  At least it hasn't revealed something bad was happening to me.  Its usually just people geeking out about this or that aspect of an answer/question.

Comment: @Will Programmers gets some mileage out of the "20 comments" flag. A lot of posts tend to degenerate into lengthy discussions and/or religious arguments, so we've been using the flag to identify comment clusters that have veered off course and directing people to chat instead.